# How do you add conditional formatting to a Google sheet using gspread_formatting that colors a cell after comparing it to another cell?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread, gspread-formatting

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395886/highlight-cells-in-a-column-in-google-spreadsheet-when-the-value-above-a-thresho) about a fixed threshold but instead, I want each row in column B to be compared to the same row in column A and turn red if B>A.

I tried something like this, except that the second argument in `BooleanCondition` only accepts lists of hard-coded values, not grid ranges.

```
from gspread_formatting import *
wks = GOOGLE_WORKSHEET

rule = ConditionalFormatRule(
    ranges=[GridRange.from_a1_range('B2:B26', wks)],
    booleanRule=BooleanRule(
        condition=BooleanCondition('NUMBER_GREATER', [GridRange.from_a1_range('A2:A26', wks).startRowIndex]),
        format=CellFormat(textFormat=textFormat(bold=True), backgroundColor=Color(1,0,0))
    )
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change `condition`  to a `CUSTOM_FORMULA`:

```
condition=BooleanCondition('CUSTOM_FORMULA', ["=B2>A2"])
```